# Strange behavior os.path.isdir(x)

Tags: python

I want to get dir list of current dir only (no recursion).

Also, I have mount point `/mnt/test0` with `ext4`.

I do:

```
>>> [x for x in os.listdir('/mnt/test0/base/trash') if os.path.isdir(x)]
[]
```

`/mnt/test0/base/trash` has one dir `test`, however `list` is empty.

If I do:

```
>>> [x for x in os.listdir('/mnt/test0/base/trash')]
```

It's here.

```
>>> [x for x in os.listdir('/mnt/test0/base/trash')]
['test']
```

Linux `ls`:

```
# ls -lA
total 28
drwxrwx--- 9 root root 28672 Nov 11 23:00 test
```

What is the strange bug of `os.path.isdir(x)`?

**UPDATE**:

I restart Python and now I get result:

```
>>> [x for x in os.listdir('/mnt/test0/base/trash') if os.path.isdir(x)]
['test']
```

It's strange at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `os.listdir` lists only the last parts of the path. Note how it returns `['test']` and not `['/mnt/test0/base/trash/test']`.

When you check it with `isdir()`, the name(s) are evaluated relative to the current working directory and not to `/mnt/test0/base/trash`. Basically you need something like this:

```
>>> d = '/mnt/test0/base/trash'
>>> [x for x in os.listdir(d) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x))]
```

Comment: Thanks. :) But I have another Q. Sometimes it returns the directory. I restart Python and I get `['test']` with `os.path.isdir(x)`. Why? Is it the strange behavior of Python?

Comment: DId you look in the directory in which you're running Python?  Is there a directory "test" in it?

Comment: @Kirill it will depend on where you run the code from (i.e. you current working directory). Your  original code should work fine if you run it from within `/mnt/test0/base/trash` and fail everywhere else.